# Best Test For Generalized/Nonparametric Behrens-Fisher Problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

First, because there seems to be a confusion of what the generalized Behrens-Fisher problem is a description adapted from [[1]](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1366138199).

We have $X_1,\ldots,X_m$ i.i.d. from distribution $P$ and $Y_1,\ldots,X_n$ i.i.d. from distribution $Q$. Both $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued. The expectations $E(P)$ and $E(Q)$ and variances $V(P)$ and $V(Q)$ are finite, real-valued and exist. The generalized Behrens-Fisher problem is now to test whether $E(P)=E(Q)$. Thus, importantly, it is not assumed that $Q=P$ under the null hypothesis, for which the permutation test is exact and seems to be widely accepted, or that $Q$ and $P$ are normal, for which the Welch t-test seems to be recommended.

**The question is: What out of the availabe frequentist hypothesis tests would you consider best for this problem and why? So if you had to perform such an analysis today, which test would you use?**

To clarify a bit: for the definition of best, I have uniformly most powerful tests [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test) in mind. However, I am aware that such a test does not exist. So, the best test would be one that comes closest to this ideal. I am aware that this still leaves quite some room for interpretation.

In which situation: The situation is as outlined. So, one knows nothing about $Q$ and $P$ besides what I mentioned. But the preferred procedure could  first look at certain characteristics of the data and depending on those use different tests. As far as I understand, this is the core idea of adaptive tests.

I found many competing procedures of which the most straightforward to me are the studentized permutation test and bootstrap, which are compared in [[2]](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02741303.pdf). One weakness of both these tests is that they are only approximately exact.  I also found an adaptive test, which seems to solve the problem [[3]](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610929608831785). I am sure I missed many more tests.